# Local storage/database method for phonegap/cordova webapp

Tags: database, cordova, sencha-touch, local-storage

I am creating a songbook webapp (Phonegap & SenchaTouch) (about 1000 songs). What is the best method to store the lyrics locally so that it is quickly searchable and accessible without significantly affecting performance.

Answer (score 1):

You just said it, LocalStorage is the best method. In a past project, we used this method to create user database and sync their records back to a data server. We tested with up to 5MB of data and it would run fine even on iPad 1 and Android 4.2.2.

**To save data:**

```
var currentTrack = {
                    "track_album": "Romance Night",
                    "track_name": "Love you forever",
                    "track_lyrics": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                   };
localStorage.setItem('track_3243242', JSON.stringify(songdata));
```

**To read the data:**

```
var readTrack = localStorage.getItem('track_3243242');
console.log(JSON.parse(readTrack));
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way I know is to:

- add all items to one JSON
- stringify the JSON
- push it to the localStorage (see James Wong's post)
- add the JSON to a store (Sencha Touch Store)

from there you can filter, sort, ...